# VLAN Inner Talking

Tags: cisco, vlan, ping, access-control-list, icmp

I kinda forgot about CISCO in general, it had been quite a while since I last touched packet tracer. Now I'm on the PRE-deployment phase of a network at work. Long story short.

-I made 2 VLAN on CISCO Router and Switch, trunking, encapsulation, all good and working

Vlan 5 Student

Vlan 76 Office

At first, with just the Switch there was no talking beetwen VLAN, but i had to add a router so VLAN could talk to the internet and server for DHCP, DNS, and Group Policy.

in order to limit talking between VLANs at all, I created some Standards ACL. All good, each VLAN can talk to the internet and server, BUT NO the other VLAN.

But now I face another issue. I DONT WANT STUDENTS talking to each other on the same VLAN, how can I limit talking within the same VLAN

[Network topology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3tCe.png)

Answer (score 0):

The feature you're looking for is called *Protected Ports* in Cisco's terms. You have to add `switchport protected` interface configuration mode command on your switch Ethernet interfaces that should **not** be allowed to talk to each other. You can apply this command to a port range if needed. The documentation for it this feature is available i.e. [here](https://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/switches/lan/catalyst3850/software/release/3.2_0_se/multibook/configuration_guide/b_consolidated_config_guide_3850_chapter_011101.html).